# RestAssured cannot pass empty/null path param

Tags: rest-assured, cucumber-java

I was trying to pass path parameter as empty/null in cucumber api testing using restAssured.

e.g. when I call endpoint as >> http://localhost:8093/my-rest-call//instructions

```
(http://localhost:8093/my-rest-call/{myId}/instructions)
```

it's giving 404 But I expect 500.
In postman it works as expected though

However if the null/empty path parameter at the end. like below I get 500 internal server error as expected.

```
e.g http://localhost:8093/my-rest-call/instructions/{path param}
```

Other option I tried was have " " (double quote with space). But in that case restAssured add that space into special characters. (`%20`)

e.g  `http://localhost:8093/my-rest-call/%20/instructions`

I am using below code in RestAssured

public static Respon

```
se request(Function<RequestSpecification, Response> method, RequestSpecification spec) {
        RequestSpecification call = rest()
            .spec(spec)
            .log().all().when();
        return method.apply(call)
            .then()
            .log().all()
            .extract().response();
    }
```

I can see path param as "" (i.e. `myId=""`) in `namedPathParameters` under `RequestSpecification` and url as `my-rest-call/{myId}/instructions` under method

I looked at below

conversation as well

[conversation-1](https://github.com/rest-assured/rest-assured/issues/631)

I am using `io.rest-assured:rest-assured:3.3.0`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Realised that method `pathParams` in `io.rest-assured:rest-assured:4.5.1` we can pass empty string

i.e.

```
RequestSpecification pathParams(String firstParameterName, Object firstParameterValue, Object... parameterNameValuePairs);
```

e.g.

```
private RequestSpecification request;
request.pathParams("uriParamName", "");
```

Answer (score 0):

You haven't posted the `Rest-Assured` so I don't know how you've tested

However, the below should work

```
given().log().all().pathParam("trial", "").when().get("http://soapractice.mocklab.io/thing/{trial}/def").then().statusCode(200);
```

Comment: I added RestAssured code into the question. Looks like I get the pathparam correctly under the spec as specified. Not sure where the issue.

Comment: Can you add a `.log().all()` and see if you are getting an empty space in the request payload

Comment: I see requestBody = """", In my code I set this using `request.pathParam("myId", "");`

Comment: Interestingly in IDE logs I can see `Request URI: http://localhost:8093/my-rest-call//instructions` and then further down `DEBUG org.apache.http.wire -  >> "GET /my-rest-call/instructions HTTP/1.1[\r][\n]"`. As you see the second log line empty pathparam is missing.(`//`). Is that expected in that log line?